# Dans quel tome se trouve « L'Élixir de longue vie » ?

Tags: littérature, philosophie

La nouvelle de Balzac intitulée "L’Élixir de longue vie" est semble-t-il classée dans les Études philosophiques au sein de la Comédie humaine. Dans quel tome de la Pléiade cette nouvelle se trouve-t-elle ? Je sais bien que ma question ne porte pas sur une question de langage, mais je fais confiance à la culture des lecteurs pour me renseigner.

Comment: "La comédie humaine T. XII. - 2" d'après http://catalogue.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/cb37050671j

Comment: @Larme C'est pas un commentaire ça, c'est une réponse

Comment: @Larme: Ce n'est pas le catalogue de la Pléiade.

Answer (score 2):

"L'Élixir de longue vie" se trouve dans "La Comédie Humaine" qui est le tome 11 de la Pléiade selon ce site :
http://hbalzac.free.fr/pleiade.php